# SVG displays as black block, is the issue with clip rule?

Tags: html, svg

I have this SVG that was exported for me from a figma file of the Visa logo for a payment page of a website, but I am having an issue where every SVG exported for this page displays as a black block when I insert it into the page, even though in the preview on webstorm it shows all the colors correctly.

Is this an issue with the clip rule? Or something to do with my website's stack? (It is inside of a liquid template)

```html
<svg width="35" height="24" viewBox="0 0 35 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="1.14893" y="0.5" width="33" height="23" rx="3.5" fill="white"/>
    <path d="M15.9156 15.8276H13.8094L15.1267 8.19705H17.2328L15.9156 15.8276Z" fill="#172B85"/>
    <path d="M23.5506 8.38358C23.1351 8.22918 22.4762 8.05872 21.6615 8.05872C19.5816 8.05872 18.1169 9.09771 18.1079 10.5832C18.0906 11.6791 19.1566 12.2878 19.9538 12.6533C20.7687 13.0267 21.0457 13.2704 21.0457 13.6033C21.0374 14.1144 20.3872 14.3501 19.7808 14.3501C18.9399 14.3501 18.4894 14.2286 17.8047 13.9442L17.5273 13.8223L17.2326 15.5352C17.7266 15.746 18.6367 15.9331 19.5816 15.9413C21.7915 15.9413 23.2303 14.9183 23.2473 13.3354C23.2557 12.4667 22.6929 11.8011 21.4794 11.2573C20.7427 10.9081 20.2916 10.6727 20.2916 10.3155C20.3003 9.99073 20.6732 9.6581 21.5047 9.6581C22.1894 9.64181 22.6925 9.79598 23.0736 9.95027L23.2641 10.0313L23.5506 8.38358Z" fill="#172B85"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M27.3205 8.19705H28.9497L30.6488 15.8274H28.6987C28.6987 15.8274 28.5079 14.9507 28.4474 14.6828H25.7432C25.665 14.8857 25.3012 15.8274 25.3012 15.8274H23.0912L26.2197 8.83016C26.4365 8.33494 26.8182 8.19705 27.3205 8.19705ZM27.1908 10.9894C27.1908 10.9894 26.5234 12.686 26.3499 13.1244H28.1006C28.0139 12.7429 27.6151 10.9164 27.6151 10.9164L27.4679 10.2589C27.4059 10.4282 27.3163 10.6609 27.2558 10.8179C27.2148 10.9244 27.1873 10.996 27.1908 10.9894Z" fill="#172B85"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9.98757 13.4003L12.0502 8.19705H14.2773L10.9668 15.8195H8.73955L6.86231 9.18924C6.21461 8.83451 5.4754 8.54922 4.64893 8.35124L4.68359 8.19706H8.07223C8.53154 8.21314 8.90425 8.35113 9.02552 8.83848L9.76196 12.3444C9.76203 12.3446 9.7621 12.3448 9.76217 12.345L9.98757 13.4003Z" fill="#172B85"/>
    <rect x="1.14893" y="0.5" width="33" height="23" rx="3.5" stroke="#E5E5E5"/>
</svg>
```

How it should look:
[image: Visa logo]

How all of the payment logos display within the page when added, svg code unedited:
[image: All of the payment logos displaying as black blocks instead of with full color]

Comment: Seems to work fine here

Comment: probably you have in the css something like `svg{fill:currentColor}` overwriting the fill attribute.

Comment: Open up dev tools in your browser and see what CSS properties are applied to the SVG elements. The issue is not the SVG itself.

Comment: In fact your svg doesn't require any `clip-rule` or `fill-rule` attributes (figma tends to be quite "verbose"). Besides, the top `<rect>` element doesn't make much sense - copy the stroke to the 1st rectangle and delete this topmost one. With regards to logos:  prefer `<img>` elements over inlined svg. Although you'll lose styling options you won't run into troubles due to something like duplicate IDs (used for clip-path, mask, gradient references) as well as class based styles that can easily be overridden by other svg styles or obviously the document's stylesheets.